# SQL - Using count to ONLY count for chosen values

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select s.code, s.id
from subjects s
join courses c on (c.subject = s.id)
group by s.id
having count(*) > 25
except
    select s.code, s.id
    from subjects s
    join courses c on (s.id = c.subject)
    join course_staff cs on (cs.course = c.id);
```

This returns the result I want except the `select s.code, s.id` line should really be `select s.code, count(*)`. I'm just using it as a test. When I use the code in the example I get 4 tuples as expected but when I switch out the `s.id` for `count(*)` I get ALL of tuples with count > 25 from the subject table. Is there a way to ONLY display count results for which the code in the example returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
select s.code, count(*)
from subjects s
join courses c on (c.subject = s.id)
left join 
(select s.code, s.id
    from subjects s
    join courses c on (s.id = c.subject)
    join course_staff cs on (cs.course = c.id)) a
on a.code=s.code and a.id = s.id
where a.code is null
group by s.id
having count(*) > 25
```

The left join of two tables (t1,t2) with null check on column of t2, will select all rows of table t1 where the rows didnt match with table t2.

Answer (score 0):

probably because you are invalidating your except clause when you swap out s.id for count(*).  I think you should somehow be able to incorporate your except clause into the query itself.

If i'm reading your query correctly then this should work:

```
select s.code, count(*)
from subjects s
join courses c on (c.subject = s.id)
where c.id not in (select cs.course from course_staff cs)
group by s.id
having count(*) > 25;
```